# tkinter display frame on click

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to display/include a function `display_srv` on a click from the menu bar command and get values of each checkbox selected with the button ***Done***

```
import tkinter as tk
import glob
from tkinter import *

def frame_1():
    print("frame 1!")
```

The function I tried to display in the frame:

```
def display_srv():
    frame_1 = root.LabelFrame(root, text="Liste Serveurs")
    frame_1.grid(row=0, sticky='ew', padx=20, pady=20, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
    path = '/home/lst/*.txt'
    files=glob.glob(path)
    count = 0
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
            for item in lst_file:
                lng = root.Checkbutton(frame_1, variable = item, text=item.rstrip()).grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
                count += 1
```

Text file value:

```
item1
item2
item3
...
item100
```

The function to get values:

```
def getvalue():
    print(list(lng.values()))
```

The main script:

```
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.geometry('700x500')
root.title("My menu")
root.config(menu=menu)
testpsimenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Test Menu", menu=testpsimenu, font=("Arial", 12))
testpsimenu.add_command(label="Select 1", font=("Arial", 10), command=frame_1)
testpsimenu.add_separator()
testpsimenu.add_command(label="Select 2", font=("Arial", 10), command=display_srv)

psimenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="PSI Real", menu=psimenu, font=("Arial", 12))
psimenu.add_command(label="Select 1", font=("Arial", 10), command=frame_1)
psimenu.add_separator()
psimenu.add_command(label="Select 2", font=("Arial", 10), command=frame_1)

exitmenu  = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Exit", menu=exitmenu, font=("Arial", 12))
exitmenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit, font=("Arial", 10))

Button(root, text='Done', font=("Arial", 12), command=getvalue).pack(side=RIGHT)

mainloop()
```

This is the error, when I click on Select2 from the menu testpsi:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./test_menu_7.py", line 13, in display_srv
    frame_1 = root.LabelFrame(root, text="Liste Serveurs")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2098, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'LabelFrame'
```

Many thanks for your help...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can i dispplay the function "display_srv" when i click on a button from menu bar

Comment: This `root.LabelFrame` should read `tk.LabelFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 problems so far.

1. You need to use the `tk.` prefix on your widgets and not `root`.

Change these:

```
root.LabelFrame
root.Checkbutton
```

To these:

```
tk.LabelFrame
tk.Checkbutton
```

2. You need to define `lng` as a global variable so it can be used in your `getvalue()` function.

Add this line `global lng` to the top of `display_srv()` like this:

```
def display_srv():
    global lng
```

Let me know if you have any questions.